# Rails nested_form without saving parent model

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, nested-forms

I have two models:

```
class Festival < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :nominations
end

class Nomination < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :festival
end

resources :festivals do
  resources :nominations, :only => [:create, :destroy, :new, :index]
end
```

I would like to have form where user can add Festival and Nominations. Scenario is following:
1. User clicks "New FEstival"
2. User fills in all festival related fields
3. Click "Add nomination", fills all nomination related fields and clicks save on nomination
4. Clicks save/cancel on Festival.

I understand that step 3 should be via ajax, so I've created the following code:

**FestivalsController**

```
  def new
    @festival = Festival.new
  end
```

**NominationsController**

```
 def new
  festival = Festival.find(params[:festival_id])
  @nomination = festival.nominations.build
 end
```

**_new_nomination form**

```
  <%= form_for ([@festival, @nomination]), :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' }, :remote => true do |f| %>
    <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :name, :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= f.file_field :name %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                  new_nomination_path, :class => 'btn' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

But I get **First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty**, because @nomination is empty. What am I doing wrong?

**Update 1**

I've modified my code:

**FestivalsController**

```
  def new
    @festival = Festival.new
    @festival.save
  end
```

**_new_nomination form**

```
  <%= form_for ([@festival, @festival.nominations.build]), :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' }, :remote => true do |f| %>
    <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :name, :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                  new_festival_nomination_path(@festival), :class => 'btn' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

With that code I was able to render form, but as you can see I have to save Festival prior user clicks "Save" button on page. I don't understand how to make a workaround? Should I start transaction? But how can I rollback it if user closes a window (not by clicking cancel)?

Comment: this doesn't answer your specific question in the sense that im providing code, but you need to be looking at accepts_nested_attributes_for, have a look at http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: @Richlewis I've already seen that episode. Do I use form_for in a proper way?

Comment: The first thing that strikes me is that your controllers are named incorrectly - if your routes use `resources` then Rails will look for plural controller names too (`NominationsController` and `FestivalsController`).

Comment: what version of rails are you using? ill put an answer up to get you on your way, but version is needed

Comment: You have `festival` in `new` method of your `NominationsController` change it to `@festival`.

Comment: @Richlewis Rails 4.0.3

Comment: Your problem is the line `festival = Festival.find(params[:festival_id])`: the festival has not been saved yet so it won't have an id. You either need to save the `Festival` first or create nominations without a festival and then attach them in the `FestivalsController`'s `create` method (unfortunately I don't have a code snippet to demonstrate otherwise I'd submit that as an answer).